# Play-services-ads 18.0.0 get crash

Tags: android, admob

i have updated ads to:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0
and get a lot of crash from users.

```
Stack trace:  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2884)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2879)
    ... 8 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Any one the same?
edit: i have enabled multidex, but i downgrade to 17.2.1 it's seem oke for now. But 18.0.0 not work

Comment: Looks like updating the playservices affected the Install Referrer class. did u check the install referrer library? as in it seems like one of the class is deprecated in the latest version of library

Comment: Also is `multidex` enabled in gradle file?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Same problem here ...

Comment: i downgrade to 17.2.1 it ok for now, and i also enabled multidex too

Comment: I have the same problem. This happens when, the user presses the open button in the Play Store after install.

Answer (score 0):

I had yesterday the same issue, I went crazy looking for a solution. For me it worked downgrading play services from 18.0.0 to 17.2.1.

It seems to be an error in that library. My error occurred when users downloaded the application and this, crash at the beginning but then it works well if you get in again.

Answer (score 0):

Change logs of google:

To avoid a crash that occurs on first launch after app install from the play store, this release requires publishers to declare additional dependencies in their build.gradle:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:17.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in 18.1.0. Please see the release notes for more information: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes

Answer (score -1):

Use together:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
```

Comment: its not working, just downgrade play-services-ads to 17.2.1